# jquery dialog plugin content size

Tags: jquery

I am opening a dialog box with a pretty large amount of data structured as an html table (about 1400, 3 columned rows). Needless to say, it loads unacceptably slow.  Any ideas on speeding something like this up?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at either paging or loading-on-demand, like this: http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/